# kotlin MutableFlow, use value or tryEmit

Tags: android, kotlin-flow

With MutableStateFlow should it use `value` or `tryEmit()`?

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val mutable = MutableStateFlow(0)

    launch {
        mutable.collect {
            println(it)
        }
    }

    mutable.value = 1
    mutable.tryEmit(2)
}
```

Not sure which one is better to use.
The [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/) seems mentioned use the tryEmit() with the MutableStateFlow, and there is [a article about it](https://blog.danlew.net/2021/03/23/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-tryemit/) (not really understand) against it.